# How do I expand and collapse a UICollectionViewCell with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iot, homekit

The Collection view cell would need to show and hide additional tools for the device being controlled. The button that collapses would be at the bottom of the UICollectionViewCell. Whenever the button is pressed it would animate downwards revealing the fan or lights extra features or animate upwards when hiding the extra features. I only need help with expanding and collapsing by using the button at the bottom of the cell. An image is attached showing an example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a height constraint for your high/med/low selector.
Connect that constraint to var in your cell class like this:
    @IBOutlet weak var checker1HeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

set that constraint to a value you want (either 0, for hidden, or 50 or 60 if not hidden)

have a method where you set the value:

```
func toggleControls(visible: Bool)) {
   checker1HeightConstraint = visible? 50 : 0
   setNeedsLayout()
}
```

If you are not sure how to set the outlet, just ctrl-drag from the constraint in you storyboard or xib to your custom cellView class.  It will give you options to create it.

Comment: @HaIR I finally got to where I work on this. Thank you for responding. I like this idea. My next question is how do i take into consideration different screen sizes for the constraint?